# Do you use nested document or multiple documents connected by IDs in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, gridfs, nosql

I have a "project" entity and each project can have many "models" (files and some metadata) and each model is associated with a "user".
So far I have considered each of the entities as a document in MongoDB, However, I find myself going back to SQl style when trying to create the relationships between them (e.g. adding the project ID in each model's metadata). Is this okay in the NoSQL world? Should I have a nested document for project which contains a list of all linked models? If yes, how can I do that considering that I use GridFs for storing the model files, while the project is just a normal document?

Answer (score 1):

In MongoDB your data model should be such that the most frequently accessed queries should be blazing fast. In this scenario , since you are using  GridFS for storing model files, you can store project,user etc as metadata for a GridFS model entry. You can then query 'metadata' and GridFS together. You can refer to this for specifics : [GRIDFS Metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516550/querying-mongodb-gridfs)